# Building To-do list website that works with append, having trouble deleting notes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

So I'm making a website as part of a school project that is a to-do list where you enter task date and time and it pops a note with your info.
I'm supposed to use local storage and it works just fine to store the notes and restore them after a refresh or closing the browser and reopening.
Problem is when I delete a note using "onclick='this.parentElement.remove()" on the icon that appears in the note, I don't know how to access the same spot in the array that stores all the notes.

I will add my code and I hope its clear enough what I'm asking, first time trying this here.

```
var tasks = [];

// onclick='this.parentElement.remove()'

function initializenotes(){
    var backup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    if(backup.length>0){
     tasks = backup;
    }
    console.log(backup);
    console.log(tasks);
    for(var i = 0; i < backup.length; i++){
    var container = document.getElementById("taskcontainer");
    var card = document.createElement("div");

    card.className = "taskcard";
    card.innerHTML = "<span class='taskstyle'>" + backup[i].task + "</span>" 
    +"<span class='datestyle'>" + backup[i].date + "</span>" + "<span 
    class='timestyle'>" + backup[i].time + "</span>" + "<i class='fas fa- 
    times 
    iconstyle' onclick='this.parentElement.remove();deletenote()'>" + " 
    </i>";

    container.append(card);
    }
}
initializenotes();



function add(){
    var task = document.forms["inputform"]["task"].value;
    var date = document.forms["inputform"]["date"].value;
    var time = document.forms["inputform"]["time"].value;

    if(validation(task, date) == true){
    tasks.push(createobj(task, date, time));
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
    var taskindex = tasks.length -1;

    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var container = document.getElementById("taskcontainer");


    card.className = "taskcard";
    card.innerHTML = "<span class='taskstyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].task + " 
    </span>" +"<span class='datestyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].date + "</span>" 
    + " 
    <span class='timestyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].time + "</span>" + "<i 
    class='fas fa-times iconstyle' 
    onclick='this.parentElement.remove();deletenote()'>" + "</i>";



    container.append(card);
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "";
    var task = document.forms["inputform"]["task"].value = "";
    var date = document.forms["inputform"]["date"].value = "";
    var time = document.forms["inputform"]["time"].value = "";
    }

}

function deletenote(){
console.log("got into it");

}

function createobj(task, date, time){
    var obj = {
        task:task,
        date:date,
        time:time
    }
return obj;
}

function validation(task,date){
    if(task == ""){
        document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Task required";
        return false;
    }
    else if(date == ""){
        document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Date required";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML (sorry for not posting earlier):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--font awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"     it didnt let me add the bootstrap dir, so 
    its supposed to be here

    <!-- my own css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>proj</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container w-50">
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="text-center headfont">My Task Board</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <form name="inputform">
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-1 shulayim"></div>
                    <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input type="text" 
            class="form-control" disabled></div>
               </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
                    <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input name="task" 
type="text" class="form-control removeTopBorder" placeholder="Your Task"> 
</div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
                    <div class="col-11  pl-0"><input name="date" 
   type="date" class="form-control removeTopBorder" id="dateid"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
                    <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input name="time" 
  type="time" class="form-control removeTopBorder" id="timeid"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
                    <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input type="text" 
    class="form-control removeTopBorder" disabled></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-3 offset-3"><button type="button" 
onclick="add()" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Add task</button></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><button type="reset" class="btn 
btn-dark btn-lg">Reset form</button></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p id="errormsg" class="errmsg">Note: Task and 
   finish date are required</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="taskcontainer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script 

 once again its not letting me add some too long stuff so its here, the 
 bootstrap scripts
    <!-- my own script -->
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I really tried my best to indent it properly but I either don't understand how it works yet or something is bugged because sometimes when I hit space it just goes down a line and I can never properly format it as code.
hope this is readable

Going to try and add everything in jfiddle

```js
var tasks = [];

// onclick='this.parentElement.remove()'

function initializenotes() {
  var backup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
  if (backup.length > 0) {
    tasks = backup;
  }
  console.log(backup);
  console.log(tasks);
  for (var i = 0; i < backup.length; i++) {
    var container = document.getElementById("taskcontainer");
    var card = document.createElement("div");



    card.className = "taskcard";
    card.innerHTML = "<span class='taskstyle'>" + backup[i].task + "</span>" + "<span class='datestyle'>" + backup[i].date + "</span>" + "<span class='timestyle'>" + backup[i].time + "</span>" + "<i class='fas fa-times iconstyle' onclick='this.parentElement.remove();deletenote()'>" + "</i>";



    container.append(card);
  }
}
initializenotes();



function add() {
  var task = document.forms["inputform"]["task"].value;
  var date = document.forms["inputform"]["date"].value;
  var time = document.forms["inputform"]["time"].value;

  if (validation(task, date) == true) {
    tasks.push(createobj(task, date, time));
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
    var taskindex = tasks.length - 1;

    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var container = document.getElementById("taskcontainer");


    card.className = "taskcard";
    card.innerHTML = "<span class='taskstyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].task + "</span>" + "<span class='datestyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].date + "</span>" + "<span class='timestyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].time + "</span>" + "<i class='fas fa-times iconstyle' onclick='() => { this.parentElement.remove();deletenote(taskindex)}'>" + "</i>";



    container.append(card);
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "";
    var task = document.forms["inputform"]["task"].value = "";
    var date = document.forms["inputform"]["date"].value = "";
    var time = document.forms["inputform"]["time"].value = "";
  }

}

function deletenote() {
  var taskindex = tasks.length - 1;
  console.log("got into it");
  tasks.splice(taskindex, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));


}

function createobj(task, date, time) {
  var obj = {
    task: task,
    date: date,
    time: time
  }
  return obj;
}

function validation(task, date) {
  if (task == "") {
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Task required";
    return false;
  } else if (date == "") {
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Date required";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("img/body-background.jpg");
}

.headfont {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.shulayim {
  border: 1px solid #0f5aa5;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.removeTopBorder {
  border-top: 0 !important;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.taskcard {
  position: relative;
  width: 13em;
  height: 19em;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  border: 1px solid #532f00;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 13% 32% 10% 12% / 0% 8% 0% 29%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-top: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
}

.taskcard:hover .iconstyle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.taskstyle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10.66em;
  width: 7.61em;
  top: 1.2em;
  left: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: cursive;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #323538;
}

.datestyle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.2em;
  left: 0.6em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.timestyle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.2em;
  right: 0.6em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.borderfix {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0f5aa5;
  border-top: 1px solid #0f5aa5;
}

#dateid::before {
  content: 'Finish date';
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#timeid::before {
  content: 'Deadline';
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.errmsg {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #2f64a8;
}

.iconstyle {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.7em;
  right: 4.4em;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #0f5aa5;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left-color: red !important;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea,
.form-control:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #0f5aa5;
  border-right: 0;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.form-control:disabled,
.form-control[readonly] {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn,
.btn:focus {
  border: 1px solid #13688a;
  width: 6em;
  height: 2.5em;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7);
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--font awesome-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- my own css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>proj</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container w-50">
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="text-center headfont">My Task Board</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <form name="inputform">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-1 shulayim"></div>
          <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
          <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input name="task" type="text" class="form-control removeTopBorder" placeholder="Your Task"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
          <div class="col-11  pl-0"><input name="date" type="date" class="form-control removeTopBorder" id="dateid"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
          <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input name="time" type="time" class="form-control removeTopBorder" id="timeid"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 removeTopBorder shulayim"></div>
          <div class="col-11 pl-0"><input type="text" class="form-control removeTopBorder" disabled></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-3 offset-3"><button type="button" onclick="add()" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Add task</button></div>
          <div class="col-6"><button type="reset" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Reset form</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-12">
            <p id="errormsg" class="errmsg">Note: Task and finish date are required</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="taskcontainer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- my own script -->
  <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too? It seems to be necessary for a [MCVE]

Comment: I am on it right now, still getting used to posting here sorry

Comment: can you change `onclick='this.parentElement.remove();deletenote()'` to `onclick='() => {this.parentElement.remove();deletenote()}'`

Comment: you want to run `this.parentElement.remove()` or `deletenote()` on `onclick` if both then change it to the above comment'

Comment: @SRThapa I want to do both, one to remove the note from the screen and the function is supposed to delete it from the array, the code you posted is "=> " a literal part of it? or how do i do that otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

change your  `initializenotes()`

```
function initializenotes(){
    var backup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    if(backup && backup.length>0){
     tasks = backup;
    }
    console.log('backup',backup);
    console.log('tasks', tasks);
    if (backup && backup.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < backup.length; i++){
        var container = document.getElementById("taskcontainer");
        var card = document.createElement("div");

        card.className = "taskcard";
        card.innerHTML = "<span class='taskstyle'>" + backup[i].task + "</span>" 
        +"<span class='datestyle'>" + backup[i].date + "</span>" + "<span class='timestyle'>" + backup[i].time + "</span>" + "<i class='fas fa-times iconstyle' onclick='this.parentElement.remove();deletenote("+i+")'>" + " </i>";

        container.append(card);
        }
      }
    }
```

change in your `add()`

```
 function add(){
    var task = document.forms["inputform"]["task"].value;
    var date = document.forms["inputform"]["date"].value;
    var time = document.forms["inputform"]["time"].value;

    if(validation(task, date) == true){
    tasks.push(createobj(task, date, time));
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
    var taskindex = tasks.length -1;

    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var container = document.getElementById("taskcontainer");


    card.className = "taskcard";
    card.innerHTML = "<span class='taskstyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].task + "</span>" +"<span class='datestyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].date + "</span>" 
    + " <span class='timestyle'>" + tasks[taskindex].time + "</span>" + "<i class='fas fa-times iconstyle' onclick='this.parentElement.remove();deletenote("+taskindex +")'>" + "</i>";



    container.append(card);
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "";
    var task = document.forms["inputform"]["task"].value = "";
    var date = document.forms["inputform"]["date"].value = "";
    var time = document.forms["inputform"]["time"].value = "";
    }

}
```

Add your to `deletenote()`

```
function deletenote(taskIndex) {
   var localTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
   var newTask = localTask.filter((item, index) => index !== taskIndex);
   localStorage.removeItem('tasks')
   localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(newTask))
}
```

Comment: index as in the var i made var taskindex = tasks.length -1; ?

Comment: I just tried to make something like that but it seems i cant send anything into the function when its typed in like that (appended into the document).

Comment: from which array you want to delete it from `task` array or `backup` array

Comment: from "tasks" array which is the global array. i did something like this "    tasks.splice(taskindex,1);" but of course it doesent work as the index is wrong (i just added taskindex into the function itself and made it equal to tasks.length-1 just for the example)

Comment: i will try, might take a moment as im new here

Comment: Ok it was a lot easier than i thought, posted. (css is a bit messed up but you get the idea) edit: i just tried to run it and it seems to not work in jsfiddle

Comment: i will try it in my local machine

Comment: A good friend and I spoke for like 45 minutes and he helped me figure out what i want to do, should i post it as an answer to my own question?

Comment: i have worked it on  my local machine it works check it out

Comment: Please let me know how i can run your version of it edit: nevermind i see you updated your answer im looking into it now thank you very much ill be back with a result on my machine

Comment: first just use the same code you posted in the question and comment your  three functions `initializenotes(), add() and  deletenote()` and add  three functions `initializenotes(), add() and  deletenote()` from my answer to the code. it works after your click the 'X' button

Comment: OK so your way absolutely works perfectly, i still need to go over your code a few more times until i understand exactly whats going on there but it works, and now i have 2 correct answers for this problem, thank you very much and please tell me how to set it so i mark your answer as the one that worked

Comment: have not changed much you can easily understand it

Comment: it was my pleasure to help you out. i have updated last line of the `deletenote()`